# How to insert a variable value into javascript:(here)

Tags: javascript

I want to insert the value after ^ into  javascript:DoRowAny(here)

```
var totalApps = 0^NOT_DECIDED~P~TUYTR78YT; //dynamically generated
var totalNumber = totalApps.split('^')[0];
var totalId = totalApps.split('^')[1];

var totalapp = '<a class="app" data-placement="top" data-original-title="' + totalNumber + ' in total."href="javascript:DoRowAny();" >' + totalNumber + ' not decided.</a>' ;
```

javascript:DoRowAny(totalId) // I thought this would work but it does not. Pure javascript not jquery.

```
<a class="tooltip-item action-reqd" data-placement="top" data-original-title="View 0 applications<br>requiring pre-decision action." target="_parent" href='javascript:DoRowAny("YES_DECIDED~YD~TPPEUR98UYD01");'>0</a>


function DoRowAny(id) // 
     {  
            document.getElementById('#inputOne').value=id;  //inserts the value of the id into the input
            document.getElementById('#buttonThree').click(); //and then clicks button 3
            return true;
            };
```

Comment: Did you mean for that to be a string? `var totalApps = "0^NOT_DECIDED~P~TUYTR78YT";`

Comment: Did you open the console? If it's written like in the question, that's a syntax error.

Comment: It should be like this  javascript:DoRowAny("YES_DECIDED~YD~TPP06HYT1"); when you roll over the mouse in the anchor

Comment: Add your html too & what is `DoRowAny()` method??

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

Use escaped `'`

```
var totalapp = '<a class="app" data-placement="top" data-original-title="' + totalNumber + ' in total." href="javascript:DoRowAny(\''+totalId+'\');" >' + totalNumber + ' not decided.</a>';
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/bddm4tqm/5/)

Comment: Thanks but what I want is javascript:DoRowAny("YES_DECIDED~YD~TPP06HYT1"); instead of javascript:DoRowAny(''+totalId );